# App restart intent of resume android

Tags: java, android

App restarts intent of resume.When I press the app icon app restart, but I want it to resume. I am using or inflating fragment on one activity and lots of layout in on fragment visibility changing.So please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us give you a great answer, it would help us if you have a glance at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. It would be also useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: add code here. It will be easy for you to get answer.

Comment: @avdhesh moriya, Hi there are many ways in which your app might not be starting when you click on the application. Like for example if you must be finishing the application when onpause or calling super.onBackPress() or many more... SO please provide some hint/code....

Comment: @GauravADubey yes i am using on back press so should i stop using it ??

Comment: @avdhesh moriya see if you are using finish() somewhere and yes remove onBackPress() or handle it properly the way you want. When you call super.onBackPress() if there is some activity that has been opened perviouly it will open that activity or else it will close the app.

Comment: @GauravADubey One more problem is that if activity resume even on app icon click before that splash screen appearing

Comment: @avdhesh see there are many things in Android and when you pass the app to background its upto the Android to handle it. If there is too much stack in background then it will not resume from the beginning.

Comment: @GauravADubey thank you very much buddy ....

Comment: @avdhesh moriya. Posting it as the final answer in below section. Perhaps if I helped you then accept it as answered.

Comment: @avdheshmoriya I have posted the answer below. Could you please mark it as solved in below given answer, it would really appreciate me and also get me some points :)

Answer (score 0):

@avdhesh 
Point 1) 
if you are using finish() somewhere and yes remove onBackPress() or handle it properly the way you want. When you call super.onBackPress() if there is some activity that has been opened perviouly it will open that activity or else it will close the app

Point 2) There are many things in Android, when you pass the app to background its upto the Android to handle it. If there is too much stack in background then it will not resume from the beginning.